# using an href in react doens't direct to the wanted page, and i get an error when i try to use <link>

Tags: reactjs

The following code shows up in the browser, but it just refreshes to the same page when clicked:

```
<Button className="login-btn" variant="outline-dark" href="Login.jsx">Sign in</Button>
```

or:

```
<a href="Login.jsx">Sign in</a>
```

I try using `<link>`, and I get the following error:

```
The above error occurred in the <Link> component:
    at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43308:5)
    at div
    at App
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

It also gives me an error about `useHref()`, which I'm not using..

Comment: Could you please post the error.

Comment: Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    at invariant (index.tsx:19:1)
    at useHref (index.tsx:353:1)
    at LinkWithRef (index.tsx:256:1)

Comment: at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14409:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:16479:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18527:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3381:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3431:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:3496:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23394:1)

Comment: I had to write it in two different comments, since it's too long for one, but it's one error.

Comment: You should have edited the question. Did you set up the router? It looks like you did not, that's why it throws when using `<Link>` component.

Comment: what do you mean by setting up the router?

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation

Comment: I installed it, and now reinstalled it, and it still doesn't work. I'm including my code, please tell me if I'm missing something:                    function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <br></br>
      <Link to="/Login.jsx">Sign in</Link>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <h1>Magical Tours</h1>
      <br></br>
      <Filters />
      <br></br>
      <VacationSpots />
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: Follow the  installation guide I linked carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it refreshes on clicking the button is that you are passing `Login.jsx` as the `href` attribute which expects a URL/route defined in your application and I am assuming you are passing the same `Login.jsx` as the value for `to` attribute to the `Link` tag and because of that the error is occurring. If you want to redirect to the Login page on clicking `Sign in` then you can use it like this -

```
<a href="/login">Sign in</a>
```

Comment: I tried that, it still just refreshes the current page, though on the URL it shows as though it's directed to the currect page.